# Split array based on values in another array of equal length - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have two Javascript arrays of equal length with the following structure:

```
var inputLabels = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"];
var inputValues = [5, 4, 6, 0.01, 7, 12, 2, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 98.7];
```

The items in inputValues correspond to the item at that index in inputLabels.

I want to split inputValues into a new array of arrays based on the labels (A,B & C) in inputLabels, while also creating a new array of unique label values so that I get:

```
var splitLabels = ["A", "B", "C"];
var splitData = [
                [5, 4, 6, 7, 12, 2],
                [0.01, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01],
                [98.7]
                ];
```

where the index of each item in splitLabels corresponds to the correct subarray in splitValues.

Ideally the solution would be generic so that inputLabels can have more than three unique values (e.g. "A", "B", "C", "D", "E") and can therefore result in more than three subarrays in splitValues.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function groupData(labels, values) {
  return labels.reduce(function(hash, lab, i) { // for each label lab
    if(hash[lab])                               // if there is an array for the values of this label
      hash[lab].push(values[i]);                // push the according value into that array
    else                                        // if there isn't an array for it
      hash[lab] = [ values[i] ];                // then create one that initially contains the according value
    return hash;
  }, {});
}

var inputLabels = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"];
var inputValues = [5, 4, 6, 0.01, 7, 12, 2, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 98.7];

console.log(groupData(inputLabels, inputValues));
```

The function `groupData` will return an object in this format:

```
{
    "Label1": [ values of "Label1" ],
    "Label2": [ values of "Label2" ],
    // ...
}
```

which I think is much organized than your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using `Array#map`.

```js
var inputLabels = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"],
    inputValues = [5, 4, 6, 0.01, 7, 12, 2, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 98.7],
    hash = [...new Set(inputLabels)],
    res = hash.map(v => inputLabels.map((c,i) => c == v ? inputValues[i] : null).filter(z => z));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hash), JSON.stringify(res));
```